# Proof that a sequence $(x_n)_{n \ge 1}$ such that $|x_{n+1} - x_n| < \frac{1}{n}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm studying for a test and I came across this exercise:

Let $(x_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be a sequence such that

$x_{2n-1} \le x_{2n+1} \le x_{2n+2} \le x_{2n}, \hspace4ex |x_{n+1} - x_n| < \frac{1}{n}$

Prove that the sequence converges.

---

I've been stuck on this question for a while now, by doing some arithmetics I've gotten a few inequalities, namely:

(1) $x_{2n} - x_{2n+1} < \frac{1}{2n}$

(2) $x_{2n+2} - x_{2n+1} < \frac{1}{2n+1}$

(3) $x_{2n} - x_{2n-1} < \frac{1}{2n-1}$

But I have no idea where to go from here, or even if those inequalities are useful at all.

Comment: HInt: The odd indices are a monotonically increasing sequence that is bounded above by $x_2$. Hence, it converges to a limit $L_o$. Similarly with the even indices that converge to $L_e$. Finally, show $L_o = L_e$.

Comment: What argument should be made that the sequence is bound above by $x_2$? I can see that $x_2$ is an upper bound and that $x_1$ is a lower bound by expanding that inequality for a few values of $n$, since the place where it expands is "in the middle"(one odd indexed element after the last odd index, and one even indexed element before the first even index) But I don't know how I should express that in my proof.

Comment: Can you use the theorem that every cauchy sequence is convergent and prove that this sequence is a cauchy sequence?

Comment: @49328481I can't use that theorem, or rather I could if I first proved the theorem and then proceeded to prove that this sequence in particular is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: You get it immediately from the inequality chain $x_{2n+1} \leq x_{2n+2} \leq x_{2n} \leq x_{2n-2} \leq \ldots \leq x_2$.

Comment: @49328481 I don't think it's easy to show that the sequence is Cauchy. Note that $\sum 1/i = \infty$, so how can we show that $ |x_n - x_m| < \epsilon$?

Comment: @CalvinLin yes, it was a bad idea. The proof by $L_o = L_e$ is much easier.

Comment: As an example of such a sequence consider the horizontal position of a ball bouncing between two walls which are slowly closing in towards their mutual center.

Answer (score 2):

**Argument may need some minimal corrections** We have the sequence $x_{2n+1}$ increasing and bounded above by $x_2$, you could try by induction as $x_1\leq x_3\leq x_5\leq x_7\leq x_9 \leq x_{10}\leq x_8\leq x_6\leq x_4\leq x_2$, so for any $n$, $x_{2n+1}\leq x_2$. Then by the Bolzano theorem, it has a subsequence (the odd subsequence has a subsequence $y_{{n}_k}$ which converges to $X$). Then if $x_{2n+1}$ is convengent it should converges to $X$. Notice that $y_{n_k}=x_{2n+1+2p}$ for some $p(n)=p>0$, and $$|x_{2n+1}- X|\leq |x_{2n+1}-y_{n_k}|+|y_{n_k}-X|$$ here you know how to make $|y_{n_k}-X|$ small, it remains to deal with $$|x_{2n+1}-y_{n_k}|=|x_{2n+1}-x_{2n+2}+x_{2n+2}-x_{2n+3}+x_{2n+3}-\cdots+x_{2n+1+2(p-1)}-x_{2n+1+2p}|\leq \frac{2p}{2n+1}\to 0$$ then the next step is to notice $|x_{2n+1}-x_{2n}|<\frac{1}{2n}\to 0$ then $x_{2n}\to X$, so $x_{n}$ also converges to $X$. You could try to do this more rigurous.